# How i can remove gap between Menu Box

Tags: css

My problem is i dont want to give gap between box.

please suggest how to remove this gap thanks :)

My css

```
.menu:link,.menu:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
width:80px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu:hover,.menu:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

My Menu PHP

```
<?php
echo '<a class="menu" href="/test/index.php">Home</a>
<a class="menu" href="/test/profile.php">Profile</a>
<a class="menu" href="/test/settings.php">Settings</a>
<a class="menu" href="/test/image.php">Image</a> 
<a class="menu" href="/test/logout.php">Logout</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Can you show a demo of your issue?

Comment: its just same as stackover flow boxes : Questions Tags Users Badges Unanswered, as they have gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the white space between your link tags.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HfpJh/)**

```
<a class="menu" href="/test/index.php">Home</a><a class="menu" href="/test/profile.php">Profile</a><a class="menu" href="/test/settings.php">Settings</a><a class="menu" href="/test/image.php">Image</a><a class="menu" href="/test/login.php">Logout</a>
```

or

```
<a class="menu" href="/test/index.php">Home</a><!--
--><a class="menu" href="/test/profile.php">Profile</a><!--
--><a class="menu" href="/test/settings.php">Settings</a><!--
--><a class="menu" href="/test/image.php">Image</a><!--
--><a class="menu" href="/test/login.php">Logout</a>
```

or just float them left

```
.menu {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have space in your string.

You can refer followings method for creating string

where  $url is the href and $displayText is the text for display

```
$menu .= sprintf('<a class="menu" href="%s">%s</a>' , $url , $displayText);
```

Example

```
$menu = sprintf('<a class="menu" href="%s">%s</a>', '/test/index.php' , "Home");
$menu .= sprintf('<a class="menu" href="%s">%s</a>', '/test/profile.php' , 'Profile');
$menu .= sprintf('<a class="menu" href="%s">%s</a>', '/test/settings.php' , 'Settings');
$menu .= sprintf('<a class="menu" href="%s">%s</a>', '/test/image.php' , 'Image');
$menu .= sprintf('<a class="menu" href="%s">%s</a>', '/test/login.php' , 'Logout');

echo $menu ;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple solution for your problem is:

not to use gaps between all anchor tags. keep them in one line without any gap. your problem will be solved.

see below demo

```
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/creators_guru/6B9ea/
```